# Ubuntu software opening by itself?

Tags: 16.04, software-center

Basically I was just playing Oldschool Runescape and Ubuntu Software randomly opened. I'm not very experienced with Linux so I don't know if there's a shortcut that I don't know about that opens the software manager. I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS if that helps.

Comment: If you inadvertently pressed the Super (Windows) key in conjunction with the number corresponding to the US relative position in the launcher, that would certainly do it. Example: in mine, US is the nineth icon from top to bottom, so Super+9 opens US for me.

Comment: It isn't on my launcher.